# Put image in a text

Tags: html, css

please could you tell me how can I put image in text from some position (not inline="left or right..."). I have to do this without tables.

[image]

Comment: Please provide code of what you have tried till now.

Comment: in <body> I inserted <p> with a long text and <img>.

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. Are you attempting to re-create the above image? Or are you attempting to place the image inline in a way that the words flow either to the left or right of it?

Comment: Use float, and then use margin to make offset around image

Answer (score 0):

Wrap (if not already) your paragraph in a div..

then wrap your image in a div, set that divs id  (i.e. 'id=my_img_div'), and make sure that this 'image div' is in the same wrapper div as your paragraph..

then add this rule to your css stylesheet:

```
#my_img_div { 
float: right; 
}
```

The image should now be positioned at the right with the paragraph's text wrapping around it nicely.

Answer (score 0):

```
<hmtl>
<title>hello</title>
<body>
<style>
#image{ 
float: right; 
} 
</style>
<h1>text on left</h1><span>image inside (anchor)</span><h1>text on right</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hopefullt this will do the task you want

Comment: Image shouldn't be in **h1** tag. Use `  <h1>text on left</h1><span>image inside (anchor)</span><h1>text on right</h1>  `.